# Calculating periodicity of general function

Tags: periodic-functions

I have a function which is written as
$$
\left\|r_1+\frac{(1-r_1^2)r_2e^{-i\delta}}{1-r_2^2e^{-i\delta}}\right\|^2
$$
where $r_1, r_2$ are constants, and $\delta$ is variable.
This is originally from physics, which is related with interference of thin film.

I want to determine the period of this function.

Simplifying above equation,
$$
a+\frac{be^{-ix}}{1-ce^{-ix}}
=\frac{a+(b-ac)e^{-ix}}{1-ce^{-ix}}
=\frac{a+de^{-ix}}{1-ce^{-ix}}
=\frac{d}{c}\frac{a/d+e^{-ix}}{1/c-e^{-ix}}
\approx\frac{p+e^{-ix}}{q-e^{-ix}}
$$
Then whole squared term is 
$$
\|\frac{p+e^{-ix}}{q-e^{-ix}}\|^2
=\frac{p^2+2p\cos(x)+1}{(q-\cos(x))^2+\sin^2(x)}
=\frac{p^2+2p\cos(x)+1}{q^2-2q\cos(x)+1}
$$
which I can further simplify approximately as
$$
\frac{r+\cos(x)}{s-\cos(x)}
$$
Both denominator and numerator are periodic function with $2\pi$, but does division of these two still give $2\pi$ period?

Comment: You should expect some case splitting: If $r_1 = 1$ or $r_2 = 0$, then the function is constant.

Comment: I didn't put that case splitting. Physically, $r_1=0$ and $r_2=0$ is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have period $T$, then their quotient $f / g$ satisfies
$$\boxed{\left(\tfrac{f}{g}\right)(x + T) = \frac{f(x + T)}{g(x + T)} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \left(\tfrac{f}{g}\right)(x)}$$
and so also has period $T$.

**Remark** Even if $T$ is the minimal period for both $f, g$, however, it need not be the *minimal* period for the quotient. For example, $\sin$ and $\cos$ both have minimal period $2 \pi$, but their quotient, $\tan$, has minimal period $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$f(0)=\left\|r_1+\frac{(1-r_1^2)r_2}{1-r_2^2}\right\|^2$$

and $$f(\pi)=\left\|r_1+\frac{(1-r_1^2)r_2}{1+r_2^2}\right\|^2$$

and the period is not $\pi$. (And of course $f(0)=f(2\pi)$.)

Comment: Well, it could work out if I had known that $2\pi$ is the period at the beginning, but I was wondering about more general way of finding periodicity...

Comment: @user65452: you draw $2\pi$ from the period of the constituting functions, which is obvious. If you don't state the real question, don't expect a real answer.

Comment: Oh. sorry. I meant, general way to determine that $2\pi$ is period. No offense.